# Get column value as array list for distinct attribute

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to write a query to get this result:

```
[{
    "server_name": "windows",
    "app_names": ["firebase", "news api", "video api"]
}, {
    "server_name": "linux",
    "app_names": ["game"]
}]
```

However this is the result I am getting:

```
[{
    "server_name": "windows",
    "app_names": ["firebase", "news api", "video api", "game"]
}, {
    "server_name": "linux",
    "app_names": ["firebase", "news api", "video api", "game"]
}]
```

Database tables:

```
A
server_id | server_name
-----------------------
1           windows
2           Linux


B
app_id | app_name
-----------------------
1        firebase
2        news api
3        video api
4        game


C
status_id | status  | server_id | app_id
----------------------------------------
1           UP          1           1
2           DOWN        1           2
3           DOWN        1           3
4           DOWN        2           4
```

Query that I have:

```
SET @output = (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.server_name,
        JSON_QUERY(REPLACE(REPLACE(( SELECT
            B.app_name
            FROM B
                INNER JOIN C ON
                    B.app_id = C.app_id
                INNER JOIN A ON
                    C.server_id = A.server_id
            FOR 
                JSON AUTO
            ), N'{"app_name":', N''),'"}', '"'
        )) AS [app_names]
    FROM
        A
    FOR JSON PATH
)
```

I am close to the result that I want, but don't know what I am missing out on. All the `app_names` appear no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `A` from the subquery so you have a correlated subquery:

```
SET @output = (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.server_name,
            JSON_QUERY(REPLACE(REPLACE(( SELECT B.app_name
                                         FROM B JOIN
                                              C
                                              ON B.app_id = C.app_id
                                         WHERE C.server_id = A.server_id
                                         FOR JSON AUTO
                                       ), N'{"app_name":', N''),'"}', '"'
                     )) AS [app_names]
    FROM A
    FOR JSON PATH
   )
```

Comment: Why it did not work in the `JOIN` clause and succeeded in the `WHERE`?

Comment: @Jam1 . . . "work"?  Well it does "work".  It just doesn't do what you want.  You can see the difference.  With `A` in the subquery, it returns all the apps on every row.

Comment: Lol, you are right, what I meant as "work" was the intended result